# How to express this existential type from Haskell in Scala?

Tags: scala, haskell, typeclass, existential-type

I am trying to adapt [this Haskell implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6896401/3183129) of the type classes based solution of the [expression problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_problem) to Scala.  My current code is below.  I'm having problems expressing the existential type `Exp` in Scala.

How can I achieve the same thing?

```scala
object ExpressionProblem {

  // class Eval a where
  //   eval :: a -> Int
  trait Eval[A] {
    def eval(expr: A): Int
  }

  // data Exp = forall t. Eval t => Expr t
  sealed abstract class Exp
  case class Expr[T](val e: T)(implicit ev: Eval[T]) extends Exp

  // instance Eval Exp where
  //   eval (Expr e) = eval e
  implicit val exprInstance = new Eval[Exp] {
    def eval(expr: Exp) = expr match { case Expr(e, ev) => ev.eval(e) }
  }
  //                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  //                                       here is the problem

  // data BaseExp = Const Int | Add Exp Exp | Mul Exp Exp
  sealed abstract class BaseExpr
  case class Const(c: Int) extends BaseExpr
  case class Add(lhs: Exp, rhs: Exp) extends BaseExpr
  case class Mul(lhs: Exp, rhs: Exp) extends BaseExpr

  // instance Eval BaseExp where
  //   eval (Const n) = n
  //   eval (Add a b) = eval a + eval b
  //   eval (Mul a b) = eval a * eval b
  implicit val baseExprInstance = new Eval[BaseExpr] {
    def eval(baseExpr: BaseExpr)(implicit e: Eval[Exp]): Int =
      baseExpr match {
        case Const(c)      => c
        case Add(lhs, rhs) => e.eval(lhs) + e.eval(rhs)
        case Mul(lhs, rhs) => e.eval(lhs) + e.eval(rhs)
      }
  }

  // TODO: Is there an easier way to make all of them implicitly convertible?
  //
  // The following doesn't seem to work:
  //
  //    implicit def baseExprToExp[T <: BaseExpr](t: T): Exp = Expr[BaseExpr](t)
  //
  implicit def constToExp(c: Const): Exp = Expr[BaseExpr](c)
  implicit def addToExp(a: Add): Exp = Expr[BaseExpr](a)
  implicit def mulToExp(m: Mul): Exp = Expr[BaseExpr](m)

  ///////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Possibly in another module/lib.
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////

  // data SubExp = Sub Exp Exp
  case class SubExpr(val lhs: Exp, val rhs: Exp)

  // instance Eval SubExp where
  //   eval (Sub a b) = eval a - eval b
  implicit val subExprInstance = new Eval[SubExpr] {
    def eval(subExpr: SubExpr)(implicit e: Eval[Exp]): Int =
      e.eval(subExpr.lhs) - e.eval(subExpr.rhs)
  }

  // Make it implicitly convertible to Exp.
  implicit def subExprToExp(s: SubExpr): Exp = Expr(s)

  object Test {
    val exprs: List[Exp] = List(
      SubExpr(Const(10), Const(3)),
      Add(Const(1), Const(1))
    )
  }

} // ExpressionProblem
```

**EDIT**:  Meanwhile I found this [relevant StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7214438/3183129) answer and I adapted my code to it.

```
import scala.language.implicitConversions

object ExpressionProblem {

  // class Eval a where
  //   eval :: a -> Int
  trait Eval[A] {
    def eval(expr: A): Int
  }

  //////////////////////////////////////////
  // HERE'S THE MAGIC
  //
  // data Expr = forall t. Eval t => Expr t
  trait Expr {
    type T
    val t: T
    val evalInst: Eval[T]
  }

  object Expr {
    def apply[T0 : Eval](t0: T0) = new Expr {
      type T = T0
      val t = t0
      val evalInst = implicitly[Eval[T]]
    }
  }

  // Default boxing is needed
  implicit def box[T : Eval](t: T) = Expr(t)

  // instance Eval Expr where
  //   eval (Expr e) = eval e
  implicit object exprInstance extends Eval[Expr] {
    def eval(expr: Expr) = expr.evalInst.eval(expr.t)
  }

  // data BaseExpr = Const Int | Add Expr Expr | Mul Expr Exp
  sealed abstract class BaseExpr
  case class Const(c: Int) extends BaseExpr
  case class Add(lhs: Expr, rhs: Expr) extends BaseExpr
  case class Mul(lhs: Expr, rhs: Expr) extends BaseExpr

  // instance Eval BaseExpr where
  //   eval (Const n) = n
  //   eval (Add a b) = eval a + eval b
  //   eval (Mul a b) = eval a * eval b
  implicit object baseExprInstance extends Eval[BaseExpr] {
    def eval(baseExpr: BaseExpr): Int =
      baseExpr match {
        case Const(c)      => c
        case Add(lhs, rhs) => exprInstance.eval(lhs) + exprInstance.eval(rhs)
        case Mul(lhs, rhs) => exprInstance.eval(lhs) + exprInstance.eval(rhs)
      }
  }

  // Implicit conversions for all base expressions
  implicit def baseExprToExpr[T <: BaseExpr](t: T): Expr = Expr[BaseExpr](t)

  ///////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Possibly somewhere else (in the future).
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////

  // data SubExpr = Sub Expr Exp
  case class SubExpr(val lhs: Expr, val rhs: Expr)

  // instance Eval SubExpr where
  //   eval (Sub a b) = eval a - eval b
  implicit object subExprInstance extends Eval[SubExpr] {
    def eval(subExpr: SubExpr): Int =
      exprInstance.eval(subExpr.lhs) - exprInstance.eval(subExpr.rhs)
  }

  // NOTE: We don't have to provide an implicit conversion to Expr as the
  // default `box` one suffices.

  object Test {
    val exprs: List[Expr] = List(
      SubExpr(Const(10), Const(3)),
      Add(Const(1), Const(1))
    )
  }

} // ExpressionProblem
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using an extractor (`unapply`), but neglecting the fact that implicits are not by default exposed as part of `unapply`.

So this line:

```
def eval(expr: Exp) = expr match { case Expr(e, ev) => ev.eval(e) }
```

There is no `case Expr(e, ev)`, only `case Expr(e)`, because only `e` is exposed. Either write a custom extractor or find a different approach.

Scala does offer existential types of the form:

```
Expr[T] forSome { type T})
```

That has a shorthand type notation available: `Expr[_]`

Your code has a few more issues though:

If you define an `implicit` on `eval`, all implementors must implement an `eval` function with that particular signature, you can't override `eval` with an implementation that doesn't contain the implicit in the signature like you do in.

```
 implicit val baseExprInstance = new Eval[BaseExpr] {
    def eval(baseExpr: BaseExpr)(implicit e: Eval[Exp]): Int =
      baseExpr match {
        case Const(c)      => c
        case Add(lhs, rhs) => e.eval(lhs) + e.eval(rhs)
        case Mul(lhs, rhs) => e.eval(lhs) + e.eval(rhs)
      }
  }
```

Next up you are going to need to either make `T` on `Expr` contravariant or make `SubExpr` also extend `Exp`, you have a problem here:

```
  // instance Eval SubExp where
  //   eval (Sub a b) = eval a - eval b
  implicit val subExprInstance = new Eval[SubExpr] {
    def eval(subExpr: SubExpr)(implicit e: Eval[SubExpr]): Int =
      e.eval(subExpr.lhs) - e.eval(subExpr.rhs)
  }
```

If you will try to match the type signature, `implicit e: Eval[SubExpr]` can eval types that are `T >: SubExpr`, but what you require is a lower `Exp` implicit for `Eval`.

Comment: Thanks!  I updated my top post, please take a look.  The only thing that I still don't like in the new approach is that I had to drop the implicit parameter as you pointed out, but I have to explicitly specify *exprInstance* each time.  Is there any way I could avoid that?  Thank you!

Comment: @CălinCruceru I'm afraid I don't have more time on my hands, but I'd spend some time learning the ropes and the common patterns.

Comment: I guess I could just make another function, let's call it `evaluate` and place it at the top, instead of making the `Expr` trait an instance of `Eval`.  And in the implementation of all overridden `eval`s I would recursively call `evaluate`.