# Haskell: How to implement a processing on a list of different but related types?

Tags: oop, haskell, subtyping

I am from an OOP background so I cannot understand how this is done in Haskell.

In OOP, suppose that we have `Shape -> Circle, Rectangle, Square` hierarchy. I can easily write this pseudo code:

```
Shape[] shapes = [create_circle(), create_rect(), create_square()]
foreach(Shape s: Shapes) draw(s)
```

And it will call `draw` method for Circle, Rectangle, Square (or Shape if it's not implemented for a subtype).

How can this be achieved in Haskell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either use a datatype to encapsulate all of your shapes, or use existential quantification. Both options have advantages and drawbacks. You are facing the ["expression problem"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_problem). Choosing the right option depends on your architecture, so I'll just detail both.

We'll assume you have a similar definition for your shapes:

```
data Circle = Circle { circleCenter :: Point, circleRadius :: Float }
data Rectangle = Rectangle { rectTopLeft :: Point, rectSize :: Size }
data Square = Square { squareTopLeft :: Point, squareSize :: Float }
```

... along with some functions `drawCircle`, `drawRectangle` and `drawSquare`.

### Using a datatype

```
data Shape
    = Circle Cirle
    | Rectangle Rectangle
    | Square Square

draw :: Shape -> IO ()
draw (Circle c) = drawCircle c
draw (Rectangle r) = drawRectangle r
draw (Square s) = drawSquare s
```

This pattern allows you to easily add new functions (like `shapeArea`, `shiftShape`, etc...) but it's difficult to add new shapes, especially for the user of your library.

### Using existential quantification

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

-- Instead of using a datatype, we use a typeclass
class Shape s where
    draw :: s -> IO ()

instance Shape Circle where
    draw = drawCircle

instance Shape Rectangle where
    draw = drawRectangle

instance Shape Square where
    draw = drawSquare

-- Can't use newtype with ExistentialQuantification
data Sh = forall s. Shape s => Sh s

instance Shape Sh where
    draw (Sh s) = draw s
```

With this solution, you, or the user, will be able to easily add new shapes, but adding new functions could be a little more complicated.

You could also "downgrade" typeclasses to datatypes, and typeclass members to record field, as stated in [this article](https://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/haskell-antipattern-existential-typeclass/), as chi mentionned in leftaroundabout's answer.

I can't help you further, since I don't know your code in detail. If you still need help to choose, let me know in the comments :)

Comment: There's no point in having an existential constrained over a class that has only methods of type `s -> XYZ` – that's equivalent to just storing the `XYZ` results in a plain old `data` (in non-strict fields). IOW, your existential solution would better be written as `data Sh = Sh { draw :: IO () }`. (Since `IO ()` is not strict data anyway, that could actually be a newtype as well.)

Comment: @leftaroundabout Yeah I'm reading the article posted by chi on your post. I edited my post.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [typed final style](http://okmij.org/ftp/tagless-final/). For example:

```
class Circle s where
    circle :: Point -> Radius -> s

class Rectangle s where
    rectangle :: Point -> Point -> s

class Square s where
    square :: Point -> Side -> s

newtype Draw a = Draw { runDraw :: IO a }
    deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad)

draw :: Draw () -> Draw ()
draw = id

instance Circle (Draw ()) where
    circle = ... -- draw circle here

instance Rectangle (Draw ()) where
    rectangle = ... -- draw rectangle here

instance Square (Draw ()) where
    square = ... -- draw square here

main = runDraw $ forM_ shapes draw
  where
    shapes = [circle ..., rectangle ..., square ...]
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably want

```
data Circle = Circle { {- e.g. center- and radius fields -} }
data Rectangle = Rectangle { ... }
               | SquareRectangle Square
data Square = Square { ... }
```

then

```
data Shape = CircleShape Circle
           | RectangleShape Rectangle
```

Now you can have a list of `Shapes` which may contain any circles, rectangles and squares.

The main difference to your OOP code is that the `Shape` “class” (it's not a Haskell class but an ADT) is *closed*: if sombody wants to add new alternative shapes, they need to define a new type for this, or change the actual source code of the old definition.

For many real-world applications, that's actually a good thing because it means the compiler will at every time have all possible options in view and can tell you if you're writing code that doesn't cover some possible option.

Alternatively, if your *intention* is to leave shapes abstract and defined *by how they are drawn*, just use

```
type Shape = WhateverTypeYourDrawingCanvasHas
```

Comment: What about expression problem? If later I want to add a new shape?

Comment: @mahdix It's the dual issue w.r.t. OOP. In OOP you can easily add new shapes, but not new operations (you need to modify all the shapes). In (closed) ADTs you can easily add new operations, but not new shapes (you need to modify off the operations). If you already have read about the expression problem, you should probably have read about this sort of duality.

Comment: @mahdix Sometimes, an existential type with a type class can get you closer to OOP, but this can easily lead to a known antipattern https://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/haskell-antipattern-existential-typeclass/

Comment: @mahdix as I said, if you want to keep this open for yet-unknown shapes, you should probably just store the final results of the common operation (in this case, `draw`). Because if it's not known what exact shapes you'll be dealing with, there's nothing shape-specific that you can safely do with all of them in a polymorphic manner, anyway. — That said: I think this is an application where an existential type _could_ make sense, but only if you have a nontrivial class that gives you safe, polymorphic operations over the shapes. Else, an existential gains you nothing and just adds indirection.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be nice to group constructors `Circle`, `Rectangle` and `Square` under the same type called `Shape` and even we can invent a `Shapes` class to have some common methods as follows.

```
class Shapes a where
  area          :: a -> Float
  circumference :: a -> Float
  draw          :: a -> IO ()

data Shape = Circle {pos :: (Float, Float), radius :: Float} |
             Rect   {pos :: (Float, Float), width :: Float, height :: Float} |
             Square {pos :: (Float, Float), width :: Float}

instance Shapes Shape where
  area (Circle _ radius)              = pi * radius ^ 2
  area (Rect _ width height)          = width * height
  area (Square _ width)               = width ^ 2
  circumference (Circle _ radius)     = 2 * pi * radius
  circumference (Rect _ width height) = 2 * (width + height)
  circumference (Square _ width)      = 4 * width
  draw (Circle pos radius)            = putStrLn (" Circle drawn @ " ++ show pos ++ " with radius " ++ show radius)
  draw (Rect pos width height)        = putStrLn (" Rectangle drawn @ " ++ show pos ++ " with (w,h) " ++ show (width,height))
  draw (Square pos width)             = putStrLn (" Square drawn @ " ++ show pos ++ " with width " ++ show width)

instance Show Shape where
  show (Circle pos radius)     = "Circle with radius " ++ show radius ++ " @ " ++ show pos
  show (Rect pos width height) = "Rect (w,h)" ++ show (width, height) ++ " @ " ++ show pos
  show (Square pos width)      = "Square with edge " ++ show width ++ " @ " ++ show pos

*Main> let c1 = Circle (20,20) 5
*Main> draw c1
 Circle drawn @ (20.0,20.0) with radius 5.0
*Main> let c2 = c1 {pos = (10,10)}
*Main> draw c2
 Circle drawn @ (10.0,10.0) with radius 5.0
*Main> draw c1 -- c1 is immutable
 Circle drawn @ (20.0,20.0) with radius 5.0
*Main> area c1
78.53982
```

However if you would like to create an extendable datatype then it would be best to define a `Shape` class and define your shapes as individual data types which inherit the methods from `Shape` class. A good read could be this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6890589/4543207).